# Concatenate multiple arrays from data model in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have multiple arrays in a data model. I would like to take an array from each of the data models and concatenate them, then delete the duplicate strings in the array. Is this possible? I'm sure I can work out how to delete the duplicates after but I am struggling to concatenate them first.

My data model (I am trying to concatenate the application array) :

```
let productData: [ProductModel] = [
    ProductModel(
        title: "option1",
        application: ["Food","Agriculture","Gin","Metals","Poylmers"]
    ),
    ProductModel(
        title: "option2",
        application: ["Food","Agriculture","Gin", "Polymers"]
    ),
    ProductModel(
        title: "option3",
        application: ["Food","Metals","Poylmers"]
    ),
    ProductModel(
        title: "option4",
        application: ["Gin","Metals","Poylmers"]
    ),
]
```

Here is where I am trying to append the array but I all I seem to be doing is adding an empty string to each of the arrays:

```
let applicationItems = products.filter { product in
    let list = product.application
    var collectedList = [""]
    for item in list {
        collectedList.append(contentsOf: list)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flatMap and add the result to a Set to only get unique values

```
let applications = Array(Set(productData.flatMap(\.application)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate all the strings from the application arrays in a single array you can use flatMap as below:

```
 let concatenatedArray = productData.flatMap({$0.application})
```

And if you want to concatenate strings into an array of strings array you can use map as below:

```
 let concatenatedArray = productData.map({$0.application})
```